# Can't find Xcode build setting - GCC_WARN_EFFECTIVE_CPLUSPLUS_VIOLATIONS

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, clang++

I'm using Xcode 6.2 to build a C++ command line application.

The Xcode Build Setting Reference states:

*If you develop products using C++, you may need to customize these build settings in your targets:*

*GCC_WARN_EFFECTIVE_CPLUSPLUS_VIOLATIONS (Effective C++ Violation)*

However this option does not appear in the build setting list for any of my targets.

Can anyone tell me where it is?

Comment: If there is a field to supply additional compiler options you can specify it yourself by adding `-Weffc++` in that field. But I think only GCC supports it Xcode 6.2 probably defaults to clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting in question no longer has any effect - if you place it into the pbxproj file, it appears as a user defined setting in the UI.

The setting only applies to the gnu `g++` compiler, and xcode doesn't ship with that compiler any more (it ships with `clang++` and a `g++` wrapper that invokes `clang++`). a brief test of some conditions that trigger with `g++` doesn't trigger with `clang++` e.g.:

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

class foo {
    string x;
    int y;
    void *ptr;

public:
    foo() : y(1), ptr(0) {}
};

$ g++-4.9  -c -Weffc++ evil.cpp
evil.cpp:5:7: warning: 'class foo' has pointer data members [-Weffc++]
 class foo {
       ^
evil.cpp:5:7: warning:   but does not override 'foo(const foo&)' [-Weffc++]
evil.cpp:5:7: warning:   or 'operator=(const foo&)' [-Weffc++]
evil.cpp: In constructor 'foo::foo()':
evil.cpp:11:5: warning: 'foo::x' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
     foo() : y(1), ptr(0) {}
     ^
$ clang++  -c -Weffc++ evil.cpp
$
```

There are opinions that it is too noisy to be useful - e.g. the complaint about not initializing `x` (a `std::string`) is a pointless warning in this situation, and as such is more trouble than it's worth.

You can manually add the `-Weffc++` option to the compilation flags for C++ code, you can add it to the option `Other C++ Flags`, which is under `Apple LLVM X.Y - Custom Compiler Flags` (the X.Y depends on your version of XCode), but again the LLVM based compiler doesn't process that option.

> It looks like the documentation is out of date for this option - I've logged a radar to have the option removed from the docs to prevent this confusion.